# How Can I Put Keywords Into My Code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, idioms, decomposition, parameterization

Okay so how could I make my code so instead of putting 1 to 4 I could just put in a keyword like "Freezing" or "Froze" How could i put a keyword searcher in my code, all help is immensely appreciated thank you in advanced :)

```
    def menu():
  print("Welcome to Kierans Phone Troubleshooting program")
  print("Please Enter your name")
  name=input()
  print("Thanks for using Kierans Phone Troubleshooting program "+name +"\n")

def start():
  select = " "
  print("Would you like to start this program? Please enter either y for yes or n for no")
  select=input()
  if select=="y":
    troubleshooter()
  elif select=="n":
    quit
  else:
    print("Invalid please enter again")

def troubleshooter():
  print("""Please choose the problem you are having with your phone (input 1-4):
1) My phone doesn't turn on
2) My phone is freezing
3) The screen is cracked
4) I dropped my phone in water\n""")
  problemselect = int(input())
  if problemselect ==1:
    not_on()
  elif problemselect ==2:
    freezing()
  elif problemselect ==3:
    cracked()
  elif problemselect ==4:
    water()
  start()

def not_on():
  print("Have you plugged in the charger?")
  answer = input()
  if answer =="y":
    print("Charge it with a diffrent charger in a diffrent phone socket. Does it work?")
  else:
    print("Plug it in and leave it for 20 mins, has it come on?")
  answer = input()
  if answer=="y":
    print("Are there any more problems?")
  else:
    print("Restart the troubleshooter or take phone to a specialist\n")
  answer=input()
  if answer =="y":
    print("Restart this program")
  else:
    print("Thank you for using my troubleshooting program!\n")

def freezing():
  print("Charge it with a diffrent charger in a diffrent phone socket")
  answer = input("Are there any more problems?")
  if answer=="y":
    print("Restart the troubleshooter or take phone to a specialist\n")
  else:
    print("Restart this program\n")

def cracked():
  answer =input("Is your device responsive to touch?")
  if answer=="y":
    answer2 = input("Are there any more problems?")
  else:
    print("Take your phone to get the screen replaced")
  if answer2=="y":
    print("Restart the program or take phone to a specialist\n")
  else:
    print("Thank you for using my troubleshooting program!\n")

def water():
  print("Do not charge it and take it to the nearest specialist\n")

menu()
while True:
  start()
  troubleshooter()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want the user to type in the description of the phone's problem, you probably want a list of problems and keywords associated with those problems. The following program shows how you might arrange such a database and how to search it based on the user's input. There are faster alternatives to this solution (such as indexing the database), but this basic implementation should be sufficient for the time being. You will need to provide further code and information on how to resolve problems, but answers to your previous question should help direct you in that regard.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3

# The following is a database of problem and keywords for those problems.
# Its format should be extended to take into account possible solutions.
PROBLEMS = (('My phone does not turn on.',
             {'power', 'turn', 'on', 'off'}),
            ('My phone is freezing.',
             {'freeze', 'freezing'}),
            ('The screen is cracked.',
             {'cracked', 'crack', 'broke', 'broken', 'screen'}),
            ('I dropped my phone in water.',
             {'water', 'drop', 'dropped'}))


# These are possible answers accepted for yes/no style questions.
POSITIVE = tuple(map(str.casefold, ('yes', 'true', '1')))
NEGATIVE = tuple(map(str.casefold, ('no', 'false', '0')))


def main():
    """Find out what problem is being experienced and provide a solution."""
    description = input('Please describe the problem with your phone: ')
    words = {''.join(filter(str.isalpha, word))
             for word in description.lower().split()}
    for problem, keywords in PROBLEMS:
        if words & keywords:
            print('This may be what you are experiencing:')
            print(problem)
            if get_response('Does this match your problem? '):
                print('The solution to your problem is ...')
                # Provide code that shows how to fix the problem.
                break
    else:
        print('Sorry, but I cannot help you.')


def get_response(query):
    """Ask the user yes/no style questions and return the results."""
    while True:
        answer = input(query).casefold()
        if answer:
            if any(option.startswith(answer) for option in POSITIVE):
                return True
            if any(option.startswith(answer) for option in NEGATIVE):
                return False
        print('Please provide a positive or negative answer.')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: How do i give multiple solutions to each one of the problems without all the solutions being the same btw thank you so muchhhhhh :)

Comment: @KieranMcCarthy See my answer to your question [How do i split the solutions for my code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35516994) on how to add solutions to the database.

Comment: there is no `&` operator in python, use `and`

Comment: @StamKaly Your statement is false. The following expression evaluates to true: `170 & 63 == 42`

Comment: You're right, but its definitely more pythonic to use `and` rather than `&` because of readability.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for an [`enum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html)

```
from enum import Enum
class Status(Enum):
    NOT_ON = 1
    FREEZING = 2
    CRACKED = 3
    WATER = 4
```

Then in your `if` checks, you do something like this:

```
if problemselect == Status.NOT_ON:
    ...
elif problemselect == Status.FREEZING:
    ...
```